# execute command to swap caps lock and ctrl at startup

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, xkb

I'm a bit puzzled why this is not working as intended. My goal is to map the caps lock key to control. I'm using debian. For this I'm using the following command

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -layout "$(setxkbmap -print | awk -F + '/xkb_symbols/ {print $2}')" -option ctrl:nocaps
```

which works perfectly fine if I execute it via the terminal. However, I want this to be done at startup or login and always execute it manually. I've tried to add this command to the automatic startup session application in XFCE as well as putting the command in my `~/.profile`. However, both options don't seem to work. I still have to execute it manually (which after it is correctly mapped). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you starting XFCE?

Comment: @muru not sure if I fully understand your question. But I'm running it with lightdm

Comment: try moving it to `~/.xprofile instead of `/.profile`.  make sure any kbd-setup component of XFCE is disabled so that it's not overwriting your `setxkbmap` call.  make sure you really need the extra `setxkbmap | awk` interior call; in many cases a simple `setxkbmap -opiton ctrl:nocaps` would have the same effect.

Comment: @quixotic thx for the comment. I will try it. How can I check if any kdb-setup component of XFCE is disabled?

Comment: @quixotic putting the command in .xprofile didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason that `setxkbmap` command didn't after adding it to
`~/.profile` is that this file is read by your shell (which is probably
bash) only when *login* shell is started.  In `X` terminal emulators
don't start login shells.  You add `setxkbmap` to your `~/.bashrc` if you use `Bash` but there is a
better way available on `debian` systems - modify `XKBOPTIONS` section
in your `/etc/default/keyboard`, for example:

```
root@debian:/home/ja# cat /etc/default/keyboard
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Now run this command as described in `man 7 keyboard`:

```
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

You don't even have to restart `lightdm`.  Next time `lightdm` is
started settings in `/etc/default/keyboard` will be applied
automatically.  I've just tested it on my `Debian 9.4`.

Comment: that works like a charm. many thx. I have to wait 24 hours to award the bounty, but I will give it to you.

Answer (score 4):

I think the better way is to create a file .xsessionrc in your home directory.

```
cat .xsessionrc 
setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
```

This file is read at each start of your session.
This way, only your session is affected.
The others users don't get it.
It's ok on Debian and NetBSD.